# How can I upload a file to MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I could upload a file (with an mp3 extension) to MySQL Database.
I am using C++ for my application.

Thanks.

Comment: good luck, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Turorial

You will need to create a database, and a table, the table needs to have the following columns.

[name] -> [column data type]

- id -> PRIMARY INT AUTOINCREAMENTAL
- filename -> vchar(255)
- data -> TEXT

then use the example code below, and do an insert into this newly created table.

#### Guide

You will need to follow the [MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/)

> This manual describes how to install and configure MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0, which provides C++ and plain C interfaces for communicating with MySQL servers, and how to use Connector/C++ to develop database applications.

#### Requirements

Connector/C++ 8.0 is highly recommended for use with MySQL Server 8.0 and 5.7. Please upgrade to Connector/C++ 8.0.

#### Example code

```cpp
/* Copyright 2008, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.

There are special exceptions to the terms and conditions of the GPL
as it is applied to this software. View the full text of the
exception in file EXCEPTIONS-CONNECTOR-C++ in the directory of this
software distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```